# Fix YouTube black sidebars in iframe 853 by 480

Tags: video, iframe, youtube, size, embed

When embeding an HD video from youtube using the generated iframe, I notice that two black sidebars are added to the player when I use the preset.

```
<iframe width="853" height="480" src="http://www.youtube...
```

For excample in; http://www.villagedurable.org/tv if I insert the iframe with dimensions 640*360 or use the HD size 1280x720 the two sidebars desappear allowing beautiful layout.

It's true that both 640*360 and 1280x720 use an aspect ration of 1.777777777777778, multiplying 480 by 1.777777777777778 gives 853.3333333333333 which, i think makes youtube add this nasty black bars :(

Comment: If you ever figured this one out, please post the answer.  Going bananas here with my 1280x720 video, which has dreadful black borders only when embedded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After much fuss I finally found the solution.

Apparently because 853x480 is not exactly the same ratio as 16/9, the player doesn't have controls that automatically fade away.  So the video controls will take up 30 pixels of your wide, leaving it only 450 pixels height.  To keep the aspect ratio, video is shrunk and hence the black borders (or black sidebars, whatever you call them).

The solution is to use 853x510 as dimensions in your iframe:

```
<iframe width="853" height="510" ... />
```

IMHO, this is a bug on YouTube's end, since they offer 853x480 as a preset resolution in the 'embed code' selection.

From http://www.h3xed.com/web-and-internet/embedding-youtube-videos-in-hd:

> Of the four resolution options YouTube shows you on the embed dialog
>   (for 16 x 9 videos), 853 x 480 is the only one that doesn't load in
>   the player with the fade-away controls. This is because 16 x 9 does
>   not go into 853 x 480 evenly. So you'll notice that there will be
>   black bars on the sides of the 16 x 9 video. To actually play an 853 x
>   480 video in an embedded YouTube player, **you'll want to choose 853 x
>   510 as the width and height in the embed code**.

Answer (score 0):

After searching the net a while for fix of this issue I came up with nothing, I think I have tried everything and nothing solved my problem. Then driven by my logic I just wrapped the iframe of the embedded youtube video in one div set overflow: hidden; to this div and made it's height 2px smaller then the iframe height (on my video there was black border in the bottom).
So the wrapper div is smaller then the iframe and with positioning it over the video you can hide the black borders you don't want.
I think that this is the best solution from everything I have tried so far.

From this example below try embedding just the iframe and you will see small black border at the bottom, and when you wrap the iframe in the div the border is gone, because the div is overlapping the iframe and it's smaller then the video, and it has overflow: hidden so everything that goes out of the div dimensions is hidden.

```
<div id="video_cont" style="width: 560px;
                            height: 313px;
                            overflow: hidden;">


    <iframe id="the-video" class="extplayer" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/EErx017kDHQ?&amp;autoplay=0&amp;rel=0&amp;fs=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;controls=0&amp;hd=1&amp;wmode=transparent&amp;version=2;yt:quality=high;"   frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</div>
```

In my case the border was with about 2px height so I made the wrapper div 2px smaller in    height to hide the border, in your scenario if the border is on the top of the video or on the sides and/or with different dimensions, you have to make different dimensions for the wrapper div and position it good so it overlaps the video where the borders are and with overflow:hidden; the borders are hidden.

Hope this will help.